# Trying to switch scene inside a controller and it returns InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
 at cypher.choose.ChooseController.encrypt(ChooseController.java:30)
 ... 58 more
```

I get this error from the code in the controller:

```
    @FXML
public void encrypt(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    Stage primaryStage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    Parent encrypt = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("cypher/encrypt/encrypt.fxml"));
    Scene encryptScene = new Scene(encrypt,800,500);
    primaryStage.setScene(encryptScene);

}
```

This is the layout of my package:
[image]

I'm sure similar questions have been asked but I've been looking for a while and couldn'y find the answer

Comment: Change to `"/cypher/encrypt/encrypt.fxml"`. Otherwise the resource location is relative to the class used and the entry `getResource` is looking for would be `/cypher/choose/cypher/encrypt/encrypt.fxml`

Comment: thank you very much